Is there a way to speed up str_extract in my function
I am currently creating an R package with the following function:
# Define the function to process each chunk
process_chunk <- function(chunk, ictv_formatted, taxa_rank) {
  taxon_filter <- paste(unique(ictv_formatted$name), collapse = "|")

  chunk_processed <- chunk %>%
    mutate(
      ViralRefSeq_taxonomy = str_remove_all(.data$ViralRefSeq_taxonomy, "taxid:\\d+\\||\\w+\\s\\w+\\|"),
      name = str_extract(.data$ViralRefSeq_taxonomy, taxon_filter),
      ViralRefSeq_taxonomy = str_extract(.data$ViralRefSeq_taxonomy, paste0("\\w+", taxa_rank))
    ) %>%
    left_join(ictv_formatted, join_by("name" == "name")) %>%
    mutate(
      ViralRefSeq_taxonomy = case_when(
        is.na(.data$ViralRefSeq_taxonomy) & is.na(.data$Phylum) ~ "unclassified",
        is.na(.data$ViralRefSeq_taxonomy) ~ paste("unclassified", .data$Phylum),
        .default = .data$ViralRefSeq_taxonomy
      )
    ) %>% select(-c(.data$name:.data$level)) %>%
    mutate(
      ViralRefSeq_taxonomy = if_else(.data$ViralRefSeq_taxonomy == "unclassified unclassified", "unclassified", .data$ViralRefSeq_taxonomy),
      ViralRefSeq_taxonomy = if_else(.data$ViralRefSeq_taxonomy == "unclassified NA", "unclassified", .data$ViralRefSeq_taxonomy)
    )

  return(chunk_processed)
}


#' @title VhgPreprocessTaxa: preprocess ViralRefSeq_taxonomy elements
#'
#' @details
#' Process the `ViralRefSeq_taxonomy` column.
#'
#'
#' @param file A data frame containing VirusHunter or VirusGatherer hittable results.
#' @param taxa_rank (optional): Specify the taxonomic rank to group your data by.
#' Supported ranks are:
#' - "Subphylum"
#' - "Class"
#' - "Subclass"
#' - "Order"
#' - "Suborder"
#' - "Family" (default)
#' - "Subfamily"
#' - "Genus" (including Subgenus)
#' @param num_cores (optional): Number of cores used (default: 1)
#'
#'
#' @details
#' Besides `best_query`, the user can utilize the `ViralRefSeq_taxonomy` column as `x_column` or `groupby` in plots.
#' This column needs preprocessing because it is too long and has too many unique elements for effective grouping.
#' The element containing the taxa suffix specified by the `taxa_rank` argument is used. NA values are replaced by "unclassified".
#'
#' This function is used internally by every function that can use the `ViralRefSeq_taxonomy` column as input.
#' The user can also apply this function independently to process the taxonomy column and filter for the selected taxa rank in their data.
#'
#' For datasets with significantly more than 100,000 observations, it is recommended to use this function to ensure it is skipped in the plot functions.
#'
#' The `num_cores` parameter allows you to divide the dataset into multiple parts, corresponding to the number of cores available.
#' This enables parallel processing across multiple threads, thereby speeding up the overall processing time.
#'
#' @return file with preprocessed ViralRefSeq_taxonomy elements
#' 
#' @examples
#' path <- system.file("extdata", "virushunter.tsv", package = "Virusparies")
#' file <- ImportVirusTable(path)
#'
#' file_filtered <- VhgPreprocessTaxa(file,"Family")
#'
#' print("ViralRefSeq_taxonomy before processing:\n")
#' print(head(file$ViralRefSeq_taxonomy,5))
#'
#' print("ViralRefSeq_taxonomy after processing:\n")
#' print(head(file_filtered$ViralRefSeq_taxonomy,5))
#'
#'
#'
#'
#' @import dplyr
#' @importFrom rlang .data
#' @importFrom tidyr unnest pivot_longer
#' @importFrom stringr  str_extract str_remove_all str_detect
#' @importFrom parallel detectCores mclapply
#' @export
VhgPreprocessTaxa <- function(file,taxa_rank, num_cores = 1) {

  #is_file_empty(file)
  if (is_file_empty(file)) {
    #message("Skipping VhgBoxplot generation due to empty data.")
    return(invisible(NULL))  # Return invisible(NULL) to stop further execution
  }

  if (!all(grepl("^taxid:", file$ViralRefSeq_taxonomy))) {

    message("The 'ViralRefSeq_taxonomy' column is expected to start with 'taxid:' followed by taxa ranks separated by '|'.\n",
            "However, Your column has a different structure, possibly indicating that the data has already been processed by 'VhgPreprocessTaxa'.\n",
            "Skipping Taxonomy processing ...")

    return(file)

  }

  taxa_rank <- taxonomy_rank_hierarchy(taxa_rank)



  ictv_formatted <- format_ICTV(taxa_rank)


  # Validate num_cores
  if (num_cores < 1) {
    stop("Number of cores must be at least 1")
  }

  # Use default number of cores if specified is greater than available
  num_cores <- min(num_cores, detectCores() - 1)

  # Split the data into chunks
  num_chunks <- num_cores
  chunks <- split(file, rep(1:num_chunks, length.out = nrow(file)))

  # Process chunks in parallel
  processed_chunks <- mclapply(chunks, process_chunk, ictv_formatted = ictv_formatted, taxa_rank = taxa_rank, mc.cores = num_cores)

  # Combine processed chunks
  file_processed <- bind_rows(processed_chunks)

  return(file_processed)
}

The function takes a column containing viral taxa such as "taxid:2065037|Betatorquevirus|Anelloviridae" and extracts the taxa rank of interest by comparing it to the ICTV database. For instance, I can choose "Family" and virus families ending with viridae are extracted and if no information about the family is given, other details such as Genus, Class or Order are used to identify the Phylum. Then "unclassified" + the Phylum name is used. If no information about the Phylum is given, "unclassified" is used for that observation.
My problem is that both the ICTV data set and the input data can be really large. For a data set with 1 Million observation, this function can take 1.5 minutes to execute.
I optimized the function to run on multiple cores, but even on 7 cores/threads it still takes 22 seconds.
I used the profvis function and idenified str_extract as the bottleneck in the code.
My question is: Is there a way to optimize the code further.
I optimize the code: I utilized dplyr functions and let the user run the function on multiple cores by splitting the data and using mapply for each chunk.
100.000 observations on 1 core takes 7.05s to execute. 2.28s with 7 threads (I have 8 threads on my pc).
1 Million threads take 90 seconds or 22 seconds on 7 threads.
Example code:
# Only to install the current version of Virusparies. Otherwise comment out
# remove.packages("Virusparies") # remove old version before installing new
# library(remotes)
# remotes::install_github("SergejRuff/Virusparies")

library(Virusparies)

path <- system.file("extdata", "virushunter.tsv", package = "Virusparies")
file <- ImportVirusTable(path)

# repeat number of rows to reach 1 million

# Check the number of rows in the original data
num_rows_original <- nrow(file)

# Calculate the number of times to replicate to get at least 1 million rows
target_rows <- 1e6
num_replicates <- ceiling(target_rows / num_rows_original)

# Replicate the rows
expanded_file <- file[rep(1:num_rows_original, num_replicates), ]

# Trim to exactly 1 million rows if necessary
if (nrow(expanded_file) > target_rows) {
  expanded_file <- expanded_file[1:target_rows, ]
}

for (i in 1:7){
  
  
  cat("\n cores:", i, "\n")
  
  res <-bench::mark(
    ParallelCores = VhgPreprocessTaxa(expanded_file, taxa_rank = "Family", num_cores = i),memory = FALSE)
  
  print(res)
}


If str_extract is indeed the bottleneck, and chunk is an ungrouped tibble, I'm not sure you can do much better. You can try to use stringi directly instead of through stringr, but in the vectorized case the difference is likely negligible. You could also try using the ore package instead, which can be faster or slower than stringi, depending on the case.

Thanks. Is there a direct equivalent to str_extract in ore?
